# Correct access of dynamic iFrame in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, iframe, bookmarklet

Plain JS - please no jQuery suggestions - it is for a bookmarklet that needs to use as plain JS as possible.

I hope someone KNOWS the answer since I cannot reliable create a fiddle.

This code will run in the scope of the page it is inserted in - it works perfectly in Fx6-9, safari and latest Chromes on Windows XP and OSX - Only IE gives me undefined when I try to access the iFrame

```
var zContainer = document.getElementById('zContainer');
if (zContainer==null) {
  zContainer = document.createElement("div");
  zContainer.id="zContainer";
  document.body.appendChild(zContainer);
}    

var zStuff = {}; // minimise window var footprint
zStuff.html = '<body>Hello</body>';
if (!zFrame) { // did we already have one?
  zFrame = document.createElement("iframe");
  zFrame.id="zIframeId"; zFrame.name="zIframeName"; zFrame.frameBorder="0";
  zIFS = zFrame.style; zIFS.border="0"; zIFS.width="500px"; zIFS.height="500px"; zIFS.backgroundColor="white"; zIFS.display="block";
  zContainer.appendChild(zFrame); // append to div

  zFrame = window.frames["zIframeName"]; // undefined in IE8 !!!!!
  // zFrame = document.getElementById("zIframeId"); // undefined in IE8 !!!!!

  zFrame.src="javascript:'<body></body>'"; // initialise body
  zFrame.document.write(zStuff.html); // or zFrame.contentDocument.write
  zFrame.document.close(); 
  // zFrame.document.body.innerHTML=zStuff.html; // also does not work

//  zFrame.src="javascript:'"+zStuff.html+"'"; // alternative method - either one works in Fx/Chrome
}
```

Thanks for any hints and for not voting this down. I hope the SO community will be as 
helpful to me as I have been to it over the last year and a half...

---

**Update** - since the code I posted had some remnants of desperation, I changed it to

```
if (!zFrame) { // did we already have one?
  zFrame = document.createElement("iframe");
  zFrame.id="zIframeId"; zFrame.name="zIframeName"; zFrame.frameBorder="0";
  zIFS = zFrame.style; zIFS.border="0"; zIFS.width="500px"; zIFS.height="500px"; zIFS.backgroundColor="white"; zIFS.display="block";
  zContainer.appendChild(zFrame); // append to div

  zFrame.src="javascript:'<body></body>'"; // initialise body

  zFrame.document.write(zStuff.html); // or zFrame.contentDocument.write
  zFrame.document.close(); 
}
```

the above now replaces the page I am on with the code in the zStuff.html
instead of replacing only the iFrame content - it also broke in Fx

Now I have to do this in Fx which IE also does not mind but still replaces the window and not the iFrame

```
if (!zFrame) {
  zFrame = document.createElement("iframe");
  zFrame.scrolling="no"; zFrame.id="zIframeId"; zFrame.name="zIframeName"; zFrame.frameBorder="0";
  zIFS = zFrame.style; zIFS.border="0px none"; zIFS.width="549px"; zIFS.height="510px"; zIFS.backgroundColor="white"; zIFS.display="block";
  zDRContainer.appendChild(zFrame);
  zFrame.src="javascript:'<body></body>'";
  setTimeout(function() {
    var zFrame = window.frames["zIframeName"]; // this is needed for the document.write
    zFrame.document.write(zStuff.html); 
    zFrame.document.close();
  },100); 
}
```

Comment: Well it doesn't make any sense.. you already have `zFrame` referencing to the iframe. What could possibly be accomplished with `zFrame = window.frames["zIframeName"];`, even if it worked?

Comment: one thing zContainer is undefined onload because `zContainer` dosn't exist yet

Comment: at least set the variable for var `zFrame`

Comment: @Esailija: Thanks! Please see update - changed the var access, now 2 new issues appeared instead
+David: zContainer exists at the time of use

Comment: Your edit is still doing the same thing, you don't need to do `zFrame = window.frames["zIframeName"];` the anonymous function you pass to `setTimeout` already has the `zFrame` reference in closure, you don't need to obtain it again.

Comment: This works in IE7: http://jsfiddle.net/5SRdh/

Comment: Thanks I'll look, the closure did not work because document.write needs FRAMES access whereas contentDocument needs DOM access but fais in ie

Comment: @Esailija:I'll test this within a few days (I do not have IE at home) If it works in IE8 and when inside a bookmarklet I will be very happy :) I'll be back

Comment: @mplungjan, you can try it in google chrome/firefox that they refer to the same thing in here: http://jsfiddle.net/5SRdh/1/. The alert will say false in IE because `window.frames["zIframeName"];` is `undefined` but you will never need that notation anyway.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5408/discussion-between-mplungjan-and-esailija)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hack I suggested in chat:

```
var a = setInterval( function(){

    try{
    zFrame.contentWindow.document.write(zStuff.html);
    zFrame.contentWindow.document.close();
    clearInterval(a);
    }
    catch(e){}

}, 10 );
```

Since it is not known when IE allows accessing `contentWindow` properties, this will keep trying until it is allowed.

Comment: @mplungjan `onload` with iframes is extremely tricky (not firing, firing when permissions aren't ready and so on), you will end up with a similar hack except with twice the lines :D

Comment: right... It sounded like it was worth a shot. Did not have time to try yet (and the stuff to load is only the <body></body> before the trigger)